# Bytelandian gold coins wrong answer every time

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

please help me to find why i am getting Wrong Answer for this [`Bytelandian gold coins`](http://www.codechef.com/problems/COINS) question.
here is my solution [`COINS`](http://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/5461914)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <map>

#define max2(a, b) ((a) > (b) ? (a) : (b))

using namespace std;

map <long long , long long > C;

long long f(long long n)
{
    if (n == 0) return 0;

    long long r = C[n];

    if (r == 0) 
    {
         r = max2( n , f(n/2)+f(n/3)+f(n/4) );
         C[n] = r;
    }

    return r;
}

int main()
{
    int t;
    long long n;

    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--){
        scanf("%lld",&n);
        printf("%lld\n",f(n));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am new to dynamic programming,so I google for this question and i am trying to implement
from [SPOJ_Coins](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/SPOJ_COINS),
but still getting wrong answer on both codechef.com and spoj.

Comment: Please provide the complete question in the body of the question itself (not a link), and the relevant part of your code. You should also provide a test case of where your code fails to do what it is supposed to.

Comment: @amit : it gives correct answer for given test case in the question  , i thought question is little large to post here.

Comment: @amit : i have added my code

Comment: "it gives correct answer for given test case in the question" - so what test case *doesn't* it give a correct answer for...?  You should describe the problem succinctly here (cut and paste is fine - the other site license allowing - but as concise as possible).  Those other links might not be here in a month, and people want to know their SO answers may be a long-term resource for other readers....

Comment: @TonyD : i don't know,i tried different test cases on my machine,it gives correct answer but when i submit it ,it shows wrong answer

Comment: Your use of a macro for `max2`, presumably for efficiency reasons, makes the code less efficient than it could be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this problem, you have to take input until EOF. But you are taking input using test case.

Try this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <map>

#define max2(a, b) ((a) > (b) ? (a) : (b))

using namespace std;

map <long long , long long > C;

long long f(long long n)
{
  if (n == 0) return 0;

  long long r = C[n];

  if (r == 0)
  {
    r = max2( n , f(n/2)+f(n/3)+f(n/4) );
    C[n] = r;
  }

  return r;
}

int main()
{
    // freopen("input.txt","r",stdin);
    // freopen("output.txt","w",stdout);

    int t;
    long long n;
    {
        while(scanf("%lld",&n)==1)
        {
            printf("%lld\n",f(n));
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```